# How to capture the contents of stderr in a C function call from golang?

Tags: c, go, unix, io, ffi

Here is a golang program that calls a C function which outputs to `stderr`. In the real program, the function call is inside a library that I cannot change:

```golang
package main

// #include <stdio.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
//
// // assume that we cannot change this function
// static void library_call(char* s) {
//   fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
// }
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    // attempt to redirect os.Stderr to write to a pipe; it does prevent
    // writing to stderr, but does not successfully capture the output
    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    _ = os.Stderr.Close()
    os.Stderr = w

    // call a C function that writes to stderr; I would like to capture this
    // output in a buffer
    cs := C.CString("This should be the contents of the buffer")
    C.library_call(cs)
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))

    // the pipe will capture this output if you uncomment it
    // fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "testing")

    // close the pipe writer, so we can read from it
    w.Close()

    // Question: how would I restore os.Stderr here to its normal value?

    out, _ := io.ReadAll(r)

    // I'd like this to output
    // "got output: This should be the contents of the buffer",
    // but it's empty instead
    fmt.Printf("got output: %s\n", string(out))
}
```

(You can save this to `test.go` and compile and run it with: `go build test.go && ./test`)

What I would like to do is to capture the output of `C.library_call`, which writes to stderr, in a buffer, and then restore `os.Stderr` to its normal function after the call is complete.

I can't figure out how to do so, can you help?

(For bonus points, this should work on windows too!)

Answer (score 2):

I found [code from Eli Bendersky on github](https://github.com/eliben/code-for-blog/blob/9920db50ab8e61718943e6ea355944b393b20772/2020/go-fake-stdio/snippets/redirect-cgo-stdout.go) and an [accompanying article](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2020/faking-stdin-and-stdout-in-go/) that helped me figure out a solution, at least on unix. I'm pretty sure this won't work on windows:

```golang
package main

// #include <stdio.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
//
// // assume that we cannot change this function
// static void library_call(char* s) {
//   fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
// }
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

// Solution based on eli's work at:
// https://github.com/eliben/code-for-blog/blob/9920db50ab8e61718943e6ea355944b393b20772/2020/go-fake-stdio/snippets/redirect-cgo-stdout.go
func main() {
    // use syscall.Dup to get a copy of stderr
    origStderr, err := syscall.Dup(syscall.Stderr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()

    // Clone the pipe's writer to the actual Stderr descriptor; from this point
    // on, writes to Stderr will go to w.
    if err = syscall.Dup2(int(w.Fd()), syscall.Stderr); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // call the C function, and flush the output
    cs := C.CString("This should be the contents of the buffer")
    C.library_call(cs)
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
    C.fflush(nil)

    // close the pipe, restore original stderr, and close our dup'ed handle
    w.Close()
    syscall.Dup2(origStderr, syscall.Stderr)
    syscall.Close(origStderr)

    // read the data that was written to the pipe; Eli does this with a
    // goroutine in the background but this is simpler and seems to work here
    // for my purposes. Pipes have limited capacity and this will fail if
    // the output is longer than what we see here; see Eli's code and blog
    // for details
    b, _ := io.ReadAll(r)

    fmt.Printf("got output: %s\n", string(b))
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "stderr works normally\n")
}
```

This gets me farther, but if you know of how to solve this on Windows too (or that this would work on windows?) that would be great!